# ServerSocket with multi clients

Tags: java, serversocket, tcpserver

ServerSocket to be used with multi clients we attach  separate thread for each client to to work probably,but the problem is the connection works fine and accept all clients but only serve last connection. So is't a problem  or this is normal.

**Server Code:**

```
   ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
    Socket client;
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection. Please wait...");
   try{

           serverSocket =new ServerSocket(58342);            
           System.out.println("Serever Started.");
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }

        while (true) {
                try{
             client = serverSocket.accept();
                     new ClientThread(client).start();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    String err=e.getMessage();
                    if(err == null)
                    {
                       break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

        }
```

**ClientThread**

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread{

    private static Socket client;
    private static String line="";
    private static DataInputStream input = null;
    private static DataOutputStream output = null;

    public ClientThread(Socket serv)
    {
      try {
            client =serv;
            input=new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            output=new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("New Client Connected to port:"+
                    client.getPort());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your variables in your `ClientThread` are `static`!!

This means that they are **shared across all instances of `ClientThread`**. So they are overwritten each time you create a `new ClientThread`.

Remove the `static` and you should be fine.

Looks to me like you might need to read some [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: Yes you're right. I forgot that I'm working within same ID.Thank you so much. if you didn't answer I will not get it. because I will not thank of it

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing I/O in the constructor of ClientThread.

Don't.

Comment: You aren't closing the client socket when its run method completes. Add a finally block that does that.

Comment: I did it.but it didn't help in any way